# Changes to _settings.scss not showing

Tags: web, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Changes made to `_settings.scss` does not seem to take effect. I am running `compass watch` on the project and can see that it is notified on the changes made.

Let me take an example: 
If I uncomment and change the line

```
// $crumb-slash: "/";
```

to

```
$crumb-slash: "-";
```

as seen in [their docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/breadcrumbs.html), and then use breadcrumbs in my html, such as

```
<nav class="breadcrumbs" role="menubar" aria-label="breadcrumbs">
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">foo</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem" class="current"><a href="#">bar</a></li>
</nav>
```

I will still see a slash instead of a dash.

Do I need to do anything to enable my `_settings.scss`?

**EDIT:**

Also worth mentioning is the fact that I get deprecation warnings from compass, regarding lines in `_global.scss`.

Comment: Is your settings file being imported before everything else?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about app.scss. Then yes, the very first import is @import "settings". Is this supposed to be "_settings"?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Importing `"settings"`, `"_settings"`, and `"_settings.scss"` are all the same thing.

Comment: Okay. Most of _settings is commented out by default, is there any line that needs to be uncommented other than $crumb-slash in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have some weird html. Inside  you don't have to use

, so try an html like this:

```
<nav class="breadcrumbs"> 
  <a href="#">Home</a> 
  <a href="#">Features</a> 
  <a class="unavailable" href="#">Gene Splicing</a> 
  <a class="current" href="#">Cloning</a> 
</nav>
```

I just saw in source that the slash in foundation/components/_breadcrumbs.scss that the slash is hardcoded in one line:

```
/* Accessibility - hides the forward slash */
[aria-label="breadcrumbs"] [aria-hidden="true"]:after {
  content: "/";
  }
```

Maybe this causes problems for you? maybe a bug?